# Is there a word for the payment to someone who attends a meeting?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I'm looking for a word that describes the wage given to someone (a committee member) for attending the meetings/sessions of the committee.

I've done some research and have seen this question [Is there a word for payments made to freelance workers such as designers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175187/is-there-a-word-for-payments-made-to-freelance-workers-such-as-designers/175254#175254) and its answers, and ***retainer*** and ***stipend*** are the only words that I can think are the most related, but I don't think they're exactly the word I am looking for. Is there another word that would have a closer meaning?

This is my sentence:

> Committee members are entitled to receive adequate ***attendance wage*** which will be paid by the Ministry of Commerce and Industry.

Comment: I think it often called *attendance fee*.

Comment: I'd say ***stipend*** is exactly the word you're looking for

Comment: In some African countries, members are paid a   an ***attendance fee*** instead of a fixed salary.https://books.google.it/books?id=NG6hOvzActoC&pg=PA30&dq=%22attendance+fee%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CF8Q6AEwCDgUahUKEwij1auRttjHAhUCd3IKHc_JCk8#v=onepage&q=%22attendance%20fee%22&f=false. A juror ***shall be paid an attendance fee***  of $40 per day for actual attendance at the place.https://books.google.it/books?id=BzJFAQAAIAAJ&q=%22attendance+fee%22&dq=%22attendance+fee%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBDgUahUKEwij1auRttjHAhUCd3IKHc_JCk8

Comment: Is it really *adequate*? or is it just a *token amount*?  Do you have to name it at all?  "Committee members in attendance are entitled to receive [adequate] compensation which will be paid by ..."

Comment: "*Attendance wage*" is wrong, IMO. It's not a wage. You might call it *attendance remuneration*.

Comment: @Josh61 why didn't you add "attendance fee" as an answer? I actually used that in my sentence.

Comment: @Drew yeah, that's why this question is asked! To find the correct replacement for that term that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest ***[honorarium](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honorarium)***: a payment in recognition of acts or professional services for which custom or propriety forbids a price to be set.

(from dictionary.com)

It is paid as as a favour, making it distinct from a wage or fee for service of a more commercial arrangement.

Comment: I thought of honorarium too, but found (as you did in your research) that it's an ex-gratia payment paid as a favour, whereas the question actually uses the word "entitled".

Comment: Yes, it's not clear cut. But looking at some web links from British Medical Association, I saw sections such as "Aug 1, 2014 - Members of committees are eligible to claim honoraria payments for...". So you may be entitled to it, but it seems that it is normally of a value below commercial rates, and also taxed differently. It's compensation for voluntary work

Comment: No upvotes for my question, but here's your answer marked as accepted after a while. :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Remuneration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remuneration)**

It can refer to a regular wage or salary as well as (irregular) ad-hoc payments, but I've often seen it used in the context of attendance fees.

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the sentence, "Committee members are entitled to receive adequate attendance wage which will be paid by the Ministry of Commerce and Industry" to instead say (as noted), "Committee members are entitled to receive a **commensurate honorarium** which will be paid by the Ministry of Commerce and Industry."